# WordPress/PHP if statement not executing

Tags: php, html, wordpress

So I am trying to return a line of HTML in a PHP if statement however for some reason it is not executing.

```
<?php

                    $args_commercial = array(
                        'post_type' => 'sidebar_post'
                        );

                    $query_commercial = new WP_Query( $args_commercial );

                ?>

                <ul>

                <?php if (have_posts() ) : while ($query_commercial->have_posts() ) : $query_commercial->the_post(); ?>


                    <?php

                    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                    $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
                    $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];

                    ?>


                    <li data-id="0">

                    <?php if (have_posts() ) : while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php

                    $page_field = strtolower(get_field( 'page' ));
                    $page_title = strtolower(get_the_title());

                    if ( $page_field == $page_title ): ?>

                        <a href="<?php echo get_field( 'link' ); ?>" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $thumb_url; ?>)"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></a>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                    </li>


                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

                </ul>
```

So just to explain, I am looping within a custom post type (a sidebar with posts) and within that custom post type is an option to select which page you want to display the custom post type.

That is what the $page_field variable represents. The $page_title is simply the title of the page. So in theory, if the user selected page field and the actual title of the page are the same, the HTML will be printed and then the sidebar will display.

Now for some reason the HTML within the if block is not executing even though $page_title and $page_field are the exact same value (I tested them by echoing them out).

I am really not sure how to debug further and make sure the HTML displays conditonally. Any help would be greatly appreacited

Thanks.

Comment: var_dump($page_field); var_dump($page_title); make sure those values ARE the same as you are expecting.

Comment: @Kaylined I var_dumped them and they both print `string(0) "" string(22) "commercial air charter"`

Comment: So your first var is empty. if("" == "commercial air charter") is not valid.

Comment: @Kaylined But they are both the same i.e they both var dump `string(0) "" string(22) "commercial air charter"` so shouldn't that execute the if block?

Comment: And what about white chars? Try to change to
if ( trim($page_field) == trim($page_title)):

Comment: They are both arrays?

Comment: @PavelNěmec I tried.. still no execution. The whitespace doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: @Kaylined No, they are both strings, from index 0-22 "commercial air charter"

Comment: If they are both strings, they won't both var_dump 2 value's. You're doing something wrong there. This is why I'm assuming your first var is empty, and your second var is "commercial air charter"

Comment: @Kaylined Ahh okay I see. Not sure why $page_field is printing nothing but that seems to be the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the looping was messing me up. I looped through the page itself first, got the page title, and then looped through the custom post type after that. This let the if block execute. Here is the code:

```
<?php

                    $args_commercial = array(
                        'post_type' => 'sidebar_post'
                        );

                    $query_commercial = new WP_Query( $args_commercial );

                ?>

                <ul>

                <?php if (have_posts() ) : while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php

                $page_title = strtolower(get_the_title());

                ?>

                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

                <?php if (have_posts() ) : while ($query_commercial->have_posts() ) : $query_commercial->the_post(); ?>


                    <?php

                    $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                    $thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
                    $thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];

                    ?>


                    <li data-id="0">

                    <?php

                    $page_field = strtolower(get_field( 'page' ));

                    if ( trim($page_field) == trim($page_title) ): ?>

                        <a href="<?php echo get_field( 'link' ); ?>" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $thumb_url; ?>)"><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></a>

                    <?php endif; ?>

                    </li>

                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

                </ul>
```